# Unzip all files into one single file without creating additional files

Tags: powershell

I have a large number of zip files in 2 folders. Each zip file in each folder is named with the ending like some100.zip, some200.zip, some300.zip. About a 1000 zip files ends in some100.zip and so on.

I want to go into each folder, unzip all files ending in some100.zip and concatenate unzipped content ( I don't want/need each file that will be produced from unzipping) into one single file.

I am trying with the following code testing on 5 files but ending up with 5 folders named after the zipped file name and unzipped file inside each folder. I needed 1 single file which has the concatenated data from all 5 files.

```
$logList="Folder one", "Folder two";

for ($i=0; $i -lt $logList.length; $i++) {
    cd $logList[$i];

    $zips = Get-ChildItem "*.zip"
    foreach ($z in $zips) {
        Expand-Archive $z | Where-Object {$_ -match 'some100'} | Set-Content ('unzipped.txt')
    }

    cd ..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$tempDir = "D:\TEMP\some100"
$destinationFile = "D:\TEMP\unzipped.txt"

$folders = @("Folder One", "Folder Two")

del $destinationFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$folders | %{
    $zips = Get-ChildItem  $_ -Filter *.zip

    $zips | %{
        if ($_.Name.EndsWith("some100.zip"))
            { Expand-Archive $_.FullName -DestinationPath $tempDir -Force }
    }
}

Get-Content "$($tempDir)\*" | Add-Content $destinationFile
```